# How to quickly convert functions in a file/module into a class?

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Let's say I have 100 functions in a file  that I want to convert to a class:

```
def func_1(param):
    pass

def func_2(param):
    pass

...

def func_100(param):
    pass
```

I would like to quicly convert it into this:

```
class MyClass():

    def func_1(self, param):
        pass

    def func_2(self, param):
        pass

    ...

    def func_100(self, param):
        pass
```

Is there a quick way to do this? Maybe a sublime plugin?

Comment: any comments on why my question was downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression and multi-editing in Sublime to shortcut the task.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> (Opens the find bottom bar)
2. Make sure the regular expression button (`.*`) is activated. If not press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>
3. Type `def.*\(` as the searching pattern"
4. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to multi-edit all the functions:
5. Press <kbd>Left</kbd> Arrow to unselect, and type `self,`
6. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>PageDown</kbd> several times to select all text involving functions
7. Press Tab to move all the functions to the right
8. Add the class name at the top `class MyClass():`

You would still need to manually fix the internal calls in the class, e.g. if one of the current functions calls another:

```
def func_1():
    pass

def func_2():
    func_1()
```

should be manually fixed to:

```
def func_1(self):
    pass

def func_2(self):
    self.func_1()
```